# oblique asymptote for the function $f(x)=\frac{x^2-2x+8}{x-2}+\sqrt{x^2-2}$

Tags: functions

I am trying to find the oblique asymptote of this function but I only know how to find the oblique asymptote with long division. What should I do?

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2-2x+8}{x-2}+\sqrt{x^2-2}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 3):

The right oblique asymptote is the line $y = kx + l$ such that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-kx-l) = 0.$$

It can be shown that these $k$ and $l$ can be calculated as follows:
$$k = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}x,\ l = \lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-kx).$$

Now we have

\begin{align}k&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}x = \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^2-2x+8}{x^2-2x} +\frac{\sqrt{x^2-2}}x\right)\\ &= \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{1-2/x+8/x^2}{1-2/x} + \frac{\sqrt{1-2/x}}{1}\right) = 2\end{align}

\begin{align}l&=\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x) -  2x) = \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^2-2x+8}{x-2}-x + \sqrt{x^2-2}-x \right)\\ &= \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^2-2x+8}{x-2}-\frac{x^2-2x}{x-2} + \frac{(x^2-2)-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-2}+x} \right)\\ &= \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{8}{x-2} + \frac{-2}{\sqrt{x^2-2}+x} \right) = 0\end{align}

Therefore, $y = 2x$ is the right oblique asymptote.

If you do the same calculations but replace $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ with $\lim_{x\to-\infty}$, you will get the left oblique asymptote. I will leave you to do the calculations, you should get $y = 0$. I will just remind you that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, which is $x$ when $x>0$ and $-x$ when $x<0$.

Answer (score -1):

I assume the square root part is what gives you the hard time. Let's just take care of the rational part:
$$\frac{x^2-2x+8}{x-2}=\frac{x(x-2)+8}{x-2}=x+\frac{8}{x-2}.$$
Now, the square root part: For this, we will assume $x>2$ as the neighborhood of $\infty$ is the only area that matters.
$$\sqrt{x^2-2}<\sqrt{x^2}=x,$$
$$\sqrt{x^2-2}>\sqrt{x^2-4+1}>\sqrt{x^2-2\cdot x\cdot\frac{2}{x}+\frac{4}{x^2}}=
\sqrt{\left(x-\frac{2}{x}\right)^2}=x-\frac{2}{x}.$$
We have just shown that $\sqrt{x^2-2}=x+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$. I believe you can finish the technical part now.